# 'UpdateQuery' object has no attribute 'get_field' error

Tags: python, django

Is there something wrong with my code below? The intent is that when the user updates a venue the all events that are linked to the venue are marked as modified. The **error** that I'm getting is

> "'UpdateQuery' object has no attribute 'get_field' error".

What is really strange is that I believe that the code was tested and working a month ago and it suddenly stopped working.

**My code:**

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
   super(Venue, self).save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method.      
   Event.objects.all().filter(venue=self).update(modified=timezone.now())
```

This error is thrown in subqueries.py:

```
def add_update_values(self, values):
     """
     Convert a dictionary of field name to value mappings into an update
     query. This is the entry point for the public update() method on
     querysets.
     """
     values_seq = []
     for name, val in six.iteritems(values):
        field = self.get_field(name)
```

Comment: can you please add you whole model defination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kept getting the above error, but this workaround to manually iterate the related fields and call save for each one worked. In this case the modified attribute was autoupdated so just calling save was all I needed. By the same token I could change any field I want and then call save and it should worked too. (This is not ideal, but it solved my issue)

```
related_events = Event.objects.filter(venue=self)
        for event in related_events:  # Trigger an update on related events. This will bump the modified timestamp
            # Modify the event here
            event.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is copy error or not, this

```
  Event.objects.all().filter(venue=self).update(modified=timezone.now())
```

as you are filtering any field, this should be like this

```
  Event.objects.filter(venue=self).update(modified=timezone.now())
```

or this should be like this

```
 Event.objects.all().update(modified=timezone.now())
```

`.all()` and `.filter`  should not be compatible. Though i don't know about it.

Comment: I tried  `Event.objects.filter(venue=self).update(modified=timezone.now())` and it gave me the same error. Even `Event.objects.update(modified=timezone.now())` doesn't work.
It must be that the error lies somewhere else in the code. Maybe some change I made to the Event Model.

Comment: if possible can you please add you model defination in your question.